# Midnight public transport options from JFK to Marlton, New Jersey (greater Philadelphia area)

Tags: transit, public-transport, new-york-city, jfk, new-jersey

My international flight arrives at `JFK` ~ 00:00 on the 4th of September (Friday) and I need to get to my friend's place in `New Jersey`.

From the little research I did, most options are closed till about 06:00 the next day. I'd prefer not to stay at the airport for that long unless I'm allowed access to a priority lounge which are normally in departure gates.

What should I do?

Comment: Airside lounges are out, without an onward boarding pass. A shared shuttle is probably your best option, the [Port Authority transport page](http://www.panynj.gov/airports/jfk-public-transportation.html) mentions one, a quick search [found this one who offer NJ services too](http://goairportshuttle.com/john_f_kennedy_international_jfk_airport_shuttle#nj) (but I've not used them myself)

Comment: NJ is a state.  Can you be more specific?

Comment: Sorry, the address is Hearthstone Lane, Marlton, NJ 08053..

@Gagravarr that shuttle's a minimum of $200 even for the shared cab (or I'm doing something wrong).

Comment: No you're not doing anything wrong.  The location where you're going is centered around Philadelphia so you with Public Transportation you have to get to Phila to get to Marlton

Comment: So the options are to wait or bite the bullet.

Comment: @GayotFow BWI..?

Comment: @kouton Baltmore Washington International.  And no it won't be more convinient.  Best solution is to fly to Philly.

Comment: PHL also has a lot more international flights than BWI.  If you still have the option to pick your arrival airport, you should definitely change it.

Comment: @GayotFow Weehawken is still in Hudson County.

Comment: @GayotFow Doesn't matter the zip.  All of Weehawken is in Hudson, so is West New York.

Comment: @GayotFow: BWI has very few international flights, so trying to fly there would likely mean an extra connection. The fares may also be very different.

Comment: I always broke this into two legs: JFK - Port Authority, Port Authority - NJ. Mostly this was an economic choice. The 2nd leg was by guagua and they seemed to run 24/7. I don't know if that's helpful or not given you didn't say where in NJ your destination is. I lived near Weehawken/WNY Hudson County,

Comment: @GayotFow But he did say [where in NJ he's going](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/53026/midnight-public-transport-options-from-jfk-to-marlton-new-jersey-greater-phila#comment108253_53026)!

Comment: Change your flight, if possible. There are many LHR-PHL flights to choose from.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, LOL, read the edit history :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to stay in the airport until morning, you can continue traveling through the night.  The linchpin of this plan is Amtrak Train 65, which departs New York Penn Station at 3 AM and arrives at Philadelphia 30th Street Station at 4:35 AM.  [Schedule here.](http://www.amtrak.com/ccurl/83/674/Northeast-Corridor-1-Schedule-071315.pdf)  The "transit" option of Google Maps shows an itinerary that goes as follows:

- Airtrain from JFK to Jamaica Station, departing around 1:15 AM;
- Long Island Railroad from Jamaica to Penn Station;
- The aforementioned Amtrak train to Philadelphia;
- A combination of SEPTA trolleys and NJ transit buses to get you to Marlton (including a 1-hour bus ride starting at 5 AM);
- and, to cap it off, a two-mile walk to your actual destination.

If you were adventurous/insane enough to attempt this, I would just catch a cab at 30th St. Station to Marlton.  It'll still run you into money, though; you're looking at $54 for the Amtrak ticket (as of this writing) and probably a $50 cab ride as well, plus whatever fares are needed for the AirTrain and the LIRR.

Comment: $7 to exit airtran and Cab rite will likely cost more since tolls are involved and the cab will have to go back empty from Marlton.

Comment: Is the NJ Transit safe this late? Instead of the amtrack, take the transit to Trenton where my friends would pick me up..

Comment: NJ Transit is pretty safe if you compare that to NYC subways, this might be a better options. The no of trains late at night however are very limited.